# Can I set the format of an entire column except for the header?

Tags: tables, columns

I would like to italicize all of the names in the second column of a table, but presently the only way I have found to do this is to use `\textit{}` in each cell, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
PFT & Scientific Name & Common Name\\
PFT1 &  & \\
 & \textit{Elymus repens} & quackgrass\\
 & \textit{Koeleria macrantha} & prairie Junegrass\\
 & \textit{Elymus canadensis} & Canada wildrye\\
%....
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:foo}
\caption{test caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there an easier / more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the array package to specify `\itshape` for the second column, and use the `\multicolumn` command to cancel the effect for the header.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\itshape}ll}
PFT & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Scientific Name} & Common Name\\
PFT1 &  & \\
 & Elymus repens & quackgrass\\
 & Koeleria macrantha & prairie Junegrass\\
 & Elymus canadensis & Canada wildrye\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\multicolumn`, you can also use `\upshape` or `\textup{...}`, although `\multicolumn` is more general.

Comment: `\normalfont` also works.

Comment: @Antal: My idea was not to counter `\itshape`, but to cancel whatever formatting may have been set for the column. @Caramdir: I didn't think of `\normalfont`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `\multicolumn{1}{l}{Scientific Name}` (as [*lockstep*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep) [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6200/44382)) you can use `\normaltext{Scientific Name}` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\itshape}ll}
PFT & \normaltext{Scientific Name} & Common Name\\
PFT1 &  & \\
 & Elymus repens & quackgrass\\
 & Koeleria macrantha & prairie Junegrass\\
 & Elymus canadensis & Canada wildrye\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a built-in counter for the rows, called `iRow` (it's a LaTeX counter, not a TeX counter). So, it's easy to create a column specifier which will apply only after the first row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\ifthenelse{\value{iRow}>1}{#1}{}}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lB{\itshape}ll}
PFT  & Scientific Name    & Common Name       \\
PFT1 &                    &                   \\
     & Elymus repens      & quackgrass        \\
     & Koeleria macrantha & prairie Junegrass \\
     & Elymus canadensis  & Canada wildrye    \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {lll},
  cell{2-Z}{2} = {font=\itshape}, % Z stands for the last
  hlines,
}
PFT  & Scientific Name    & Common Name       \\
PFT1 &                    &                   \\
     & Elymus repens      & quackgrass        \\
     & Koeleria macrantha & prairie Junegrass \\
     & Elymus canadensis  & Canada wildrye    \\
\end{tblr}
\label{tab:foo}
\caption{test caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]