# Tabular, make a column or a row emphasized

Tags: tables

I want to create a table and to make all cells of a column emphasized. Is there a simple way to do it, or do I have to emphasize every single cell?

Comment: For rows please look at [Make first row of table all bold](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4811/1235); for columns a related post is [Can I set the format of an entire column except for the header?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6199/1235).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`>{..}` defines what to do before the cell

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% for extended column definitions    
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c >{\em}c c}
foo & bar & baz
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26):

Just worth adding to @Herbert's answer, that you can also make an entire column **bold** with `>{\bfseries}`, used in exactly the same way as he uses `>{\em}`.
The meaning of `bfseries` is discussed in detail [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139592/31839).

As stated in the comments [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/can-i-set-the-format-of-an-entire-column-except-for-the-header), you can use `\normalfont{}` to unbold the column header.

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l l}
        \toprule
        \normalfont{foo} & bar \\
        \midrule
        foo & baz \\
        bar & qux \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: This answers only the emphasis of columns. But how to emphasize an entire row?

Comment: Why does `\textbf` not work, but `\bfseries` does?

Comment: Also @normanius did you find out how to emphasize the row?

Answer (score 5):

A very elementary addon but I was unable to find this elsewhere online and it may save someone a few minutes of head-scratching: you can add multiple styles to each line with a space:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c |>{\huge \bfseries}c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Using multiple styles on a column}\\
\hline
normal & bold and huge\\
\hline
0 & 0\\
\hline
1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Thanks for helping and answering. Useful to read: [How do I write a good answer?].(https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: How is this differing from the accepted answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Only the `\huge` as far as I can see, should we mark it as _not an answer_ (comment)?

Comment: The idea of this answer is to show how to add 2 styles to a column, a concept for which I did not find another immediate answer. If this does not meet the standards of an answer feel free to delete it I was just trying to be helpful