# Bolding the first column of a table in math mode

Tags: tables, math-mode, bold, arrays

What I want to do:

1. Create a table in math mode without $...$ everywhere
2. Bolding the first column

What I have done:

1. Using `>{$}c<{$}` to put table in math mode; see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112585/23098).
2. Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12469/23098), I use the package `bm`. However, I failed to integrate the command `$\bm{}$` into `>{$}c<{$}` introduced above.

I have tried `>{$\bm\{}c<{\}$}`, `>{$\bm}c<{$}`, `>{\bm$}c<{$}`, and `>\bm{{$}c<{$}}`. Notice that `>{$\it}c<{\it$}` can *italicize* the first column. But that is not what I want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}      % >{\command} and <{\command} for advanced column specification
\usepackage{bm}         % for bold math symbols

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|}
      \hline
      2 & \sin(x) \\ \hline
      3 & \log(x) \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the LaTeX built in `\boldmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}      % >{\command} and <{\command} for advanced column specification

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\boldmath$}c<{$}|>{\boldmath$}c<{$}|}
      \hline
      2 & \sin(x) \\ \hline
      3 & \log(x) \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The difference between `\bm{}` and things like `\it` (which generally shouldn't be used in LaTeX anyway, with `\itshape` being preferred) is that `\it` is a switch that makes all text after it italic, while `\bm{}` only operates on a given argument.

Comment: `\bm` has a normal argument, thus the curly braces are argument braces. Therefore the argument for `\bm` in `\bm\bgroup...\egroup` is `\bgroup`, which disturbs the internals, thus that some bold commands are leaking out and affect numbers. However other symbols like `\int` are not becoming bold.

Answer (score 3):

If the cells in the column always end with `&`, then the following trick with delimited arguments can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bm}

\def\bmstart#1\bmstop{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!t]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{$\bmstart}c<{\bmstop$}|>{$}c<{$}|}
      \hline
      2 & \sin(x) \\ \hline
      3 & \log(x) \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

The caught argument with the cell contents is wrapped by LaTeX in `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip`. Depending on the further processing of the cell contents, they are removed as delimited argument. The spaces should not hurt in math mode.